# SQL Command works in SSMS, not through C# SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

If I run the following in SSMS, the table gets created if it does not exist. However, in my SQLCommand code, it connects and sends the query through with no error but does not create the table if it doesn't exist. Any ideas?

```
string[] tables = new string[6];
    tables[0] += ("IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[AD_Authorization]') AND type in (N'U')) " + 
                  "CREATE TABLE [AD_Authorization]([ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, " + 
                  "  [AD_Account] [varchar](255) NOT NULL, " + 
                  "  [AD_SID] [varchar](255) NOT NULL, " + 
                  "  [AD_EmailAddress] [varchar](255) NULL, " + 
                  "  [DateImported] [datetime] NOT NULL, " + 
                  "  [Active] [bit] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]");

 for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
                        {
                            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                            {
                                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(tables[i], connection))
                                {
                                    connection.Open();
                                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    connection.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: could it be down to the user you are using to run this via Code differnt to the user you log-in as in SSMS?

if they do differ try connecting as the same user you use within your project and then see...

Comment: Also: I would always use the more precise and focused `sys.tables` rather than `sys.objects` (and having to specify what type of object you're interested in) - `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE Name = 'AD_Authorization') ....` - but I doubt this'll make any difference

Comment: Why do you execute it 6 times?

Comment: There's 6 queries total just like this one.  I didnt include them so not to be verbose, they are all having the same issue.

Comment: I didn't see the indexer for tables. Thanks. In your connection string, do you specify a default database for the connection by chance?

Comment: Ahh that was it, i forgot to add connection.ChangeDatabase(txtDBName.Text); because the connection string defaults to master because it checks if the DB exists first. Thanks all!

Comment: Let me put it as an answer then so you can accept it (and not hurt your acceptance percentage.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that when you make the connection to the database, that you specify the correct database or that you ChangeDatabase the connection first. Otherwise, your objects will end up in the MASTER database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SqlConnection DbConn = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionStringHere);
SqlCommand CreateTable = new SqlCommand();
CreateTable.Connection = DbConn;
CreateTable.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[AD_Authorization]') 
    AND type in (N'U')) 
        CREATE TABLE [AD_Authorization]
        (
            [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            [AD_Account] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
            [AD_SID] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
            [AD_EmailAddress] [varchar](255) NULL,
            [DateImported] [datetime] NOT NULL,[Active] [bit] NULL
        ) 
        ON [PRIMARY]";

try
{
    DbConn.Open();
    CreateTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    DbConn.Dispose();
    // Handle your error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use sys.objects via SQLCommand. Access is specifically blocked for security purposes in SQL Server. I'm not sure if this is a default setting, or something that cannot be overwritten.